SWXMLHash - Problem accessing to some data
Good day everyone, I need your help :
Ref the xml below which is an extract with only 2 records, I try to access to the <ICAO> element and find '07FA' record to access to its other data.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<AirportDatabase>
   <AptInfo>
      <AirportRecordID>06FA</AirportRecordID>
      <ICAO>06FA</ICAO>
      <TakeoffRwyInfo>
         <RunwayID>27</RunwayID>
         <TORA>2134.5</TORA>
      </TakeoffRwyInfo>
      <LandingRwyInfo>
         <RunwayID>09</RunwayID>
         <LDA>2061.1</LDA>
      </LandingRwyInfo>
   </AptInfo>
   <AptInfo>
      <AirportRecordID>07FA</AirportRecordID>
      <ICAO>07FA</ICAO>
      <TakeoffRwyInfo>
         <RunwayID>05</RunwayID>
         <TORA>1356.7</TORA>
      </TakeoffRwyInfo>
      <LandingRwyInfo>
         <RunwayID>05</RunwayID>
         <LDA>1356.7</LDA>
      </LandingRwyInfo>
   </AptInfo>
...

I tried to write the following code but it doesn't find the record. How can I properly use the filter function ?
let xml = XMLHash.parse(strAirp as String)
let subIndexer = xml["AirportDatabase"]["AptInfo"].filterAll { elem, _ in elem.text == "07FA" }

Then how can I access to [LandingRwyInfo][RunwayID] for this specific record ? I was thinking about something like :
print(subIndexer["LandingRwyInfo"]["RunwayID"])

I thank you in advance !

Can the database be accessed using JSON? It's so much easier to use than the old XML,
it's just a one liner to decode and you don't have to use third party libraries.

Using SWXMLHash you could try something like this:
 let subIndexer = xml["AirportDatabase"]["AptInfo"]
     .filterAll { elem, _ in
         elem.innerXML.contains("07FA")
     }
 print("----> subIndexer: \(subIndexer)")
 
 let takeoffRwyInfo = subIndexer["TakeoffRwyInfo"]
 if let runwayId = takeoffRwyInfo["RunwayID"].element?.text {
     print("----> RunwayID: \(runwayId)")
 }


Thank you so much, you really made my day !!!

Yeah, this or enumerating the children property of elem is probably easiest... I wish the filter methods passed in an indexer instance instead of just the elements. I might look into that.
